# Fastlane supply: Mapping file does not get uploaded along with the APK for Android

Tags: android, fastlane

I am trying to integrate Fastlane tools for uploading APK to Playstore. Using *supply* I am able to upload binaries, metadata and screenshots to Google Play. However, mapping file (proguard file) is not getting uploaded along with the APK.

I used the command as below:

bundle exec fastlane supply --apk /path/to/apk --mapping /path/to/mapping/file --track beta

I have opened an issue regarding the same in https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/11888

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Uploading mapping file is up and working now. Could be Google API issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/11888)